# Calculating the force on one side of a circular plate submerged vertically in water.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I am having a trouble setting up this problem. Here are the givens:

Circle's radius: 22m

density of water 1000 kg/m^3

gravity acceleration: 9.8 m/s^2

The Circular plate is vertically submerged and the top of the circle is tangent with the water

The equation for a object submerged vertically should be

1000*9.8 ∫ yf(y)dy

and the equation of a circle should be x^2+y^2=r^2

This is what i thought the equation should be but it doesnt seem to give me the correct answer:

1000*9.8 ∫ y*sqrt(22^2-(y-22)^2) from [0,22]

I must be setting up the equation wrong, but I'm not too sure what it is, can you guys explain to me what I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

In that case ti is convenient use polar coordinates assuming as origin the center of the the circular plate, with y axis upward, indeed we have

- $x=R\cos \theta$
- $y=R\sin\theta$
- $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$
- pressure: $f(y)=\rho g(R-y) $

that is

$$F=\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^R\rho g(R-y)\,r\,dr\,d\theta$$